# What is the difference between type(fetch) and type(search) in Bixby actions?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

What is the difference between type(fetch) and type(search) in Bixby actions?
Is the only difference in the number of inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetch is meant for loading content as a lazy-source.  Consider it when you want to have properties that won’t get fetched until needed.  Use search when you want to process a request through your javascript (with or without inputs).

```
property (accessories) {
    description (A list of accessories for a shoe.)
    type (Accessory)
    min (Optional) max(Many)
    lazy-source (FindAccessories)
  }
```

Here is a great working example of a fetch:  [here](https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/capsule-sample-shoe/blob/master/models/concepts/structures/Shoe.model.bxb)